# Android SQLite auto increment

Tags: android, sqlite

I currently have a table called User which has a id column which is created as

'INTEGER PRIMARY KEY'

Lets say I have created two users so the table has id 1 and 2

If I delete the second user and create a third the id is 2, I need this to be 3

So it seems Android is selecting the next available id, how can I change this to its more like  a sequence number?

Regards

Comment: but u need primary key and this is working fine.why u need this ?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Make it `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL`. Here's what [the docs](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) say:

> If a column has the type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT then... the ROWID chosen
>   for the new row is at least one larger than the largest ROWID that has
>   ever before existed in that same table.
>
> The behavior implemented by the AUTOINCREMENT keyword is subtly
>   different from the default behavior. With AUTOINCREMENT, rows with
>   automatically selected ROWIDs are guaranteed to have ROWIDs that have
>   never been used before by the same table in the same database. And the
>   automatically generated ROWIDs are guaranteed to be monotonically
>   increasing.

Comment: I want `AUTOINCREMENT` without `PRIMARY KEY`.Because I assign the primary key is another column, I am using `_ID INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL` this make error.Please help me bro.

Comment: @reegan29 AUTOINCREMENT can ONLY be used with INTEGER PRIMARY KEY. As per *Because AUTOINCREMENT keyword changes the behavior of the ROWID selection algorithm, AUTOINCREMENT is not allowed on WITHOUT ROWID tables or on any table column other than INTEGER PRIMARY KEY. Any attempt to use AUTOINCREMENT on a WITHOUT ROWID table or on a column other than the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column results in an error.* [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

Answer (score 16):

SQLite `AUTOINCREMENT` is a keyword used for auto incrementing a value of a field in the table. We can auto increment a field value by using `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword when creating a table with specific column name to auto incrementing it.

The keyword `AUTOINCREMENT` can be used with INTEGER field only.
Syntax:

The basic usage of `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
   column1 INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT,
   column2 datatype,
   column3 datatype,
   .....
   columnN datatype,
);
```

For Example See Below:
Consider `COMPANY` table to be created as follows:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE TB_COMPANY_INFO(
   ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY   AUTOINCREMENT,
   NAME           TEXT      NOT NULL,
   AGE            INT       NOT NULL,
   ADDRESS        CHAR(50),
   SALARY         REAL
);
```

Now, insert following records into table `TB_COMPANY_INFO`:

```
INSERT INTO TB_COMPANY_INFO (NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY)
VALUES ( 'MANOJ KUMAR', 40, 'Meerut,UP,INDIA', 200000.00 );
```

Now Select the record

```
SELECT *FROM TB_COMPANY_INFO
    ID      NAME            AGE     ADDRESS             SALARY
    1       Manoj Kumar     40      Meerut,UP,INDIA     200000.00
```

Comment: thanks... I needed "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY   AUTOINCREMENT" for autoincrement field .. and got it.

Comment: Shoot, I had `AUTOINCREMENT` in the wrong spot. Thanks for the example!

Answer (score 1):

If speaking for **ANDROID**, yes, above answers are correct, except naming of the id column.

```
   database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
                + TableName
                + " ( rowid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,  Raqam VARCHAR, ChandBor INT(3));");
```

It looks like in Android it should be named as 'rowid'.
And with Cursor you need to instantiate it like:

```
Cursor cursorLcl = database.rawQuery("SELECT *," + TableName + ".rowid AS rowid" + " FROM " +
                TableName, null);
```

Otherwise it didnt work for me. I don't know why it so.

Answer (score 0):

Just remember for android when writing tot the database (ie. executing),

do
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (param1name, param2name) VALUES (param1,param2)

and there is no need to add a place holder for the auto increment. It will add it by itself when adding a record. If you do not declare the params that you will put in, you will get the error x amount of variables expected and you only gave x-1, and this is because you are not supposed to give any place holding value for the auto increment column