# How to get the auto generated id from db in android

Tags: android

I have made a database connectivity where the id will be automatically generated in db. for eg.10001 i have made a form when the user register in the form and submit it will be stored in the database and a mail will be sent to the email. but i need to send the auto generated id to their email how to get the id from database.

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == Register) {
        registerUser();
    }
}

private void registerUser() {
    int selectedId = Gender.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    Selection = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

    if (Name.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        Name.setError("Enter your name");
        Name.requestFocus();
    } else if (Dob.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        Dob.setError("Enter Date of Birth");
        Dob.requestFocus();
    } else if (Collegeid.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        Collegeid.setError("Enter your CollegeID");
        Collegeid.requestFocus();
    } else if (Education.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(RegisterFormActivity.this, "choose your education", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else if (Year.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        Year.setError("Enter Year");
        Year.requestFocus();
    } else if (Address.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        Address.setError("Enter Your Address");
        Address.requestFocus();
    } else if (Pincode.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        Pincode.setError("Enter Pincode");
        Pincode.requestFocus();
    } else if (Mobile.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        Mobile.setError("Enter your Mobile Number");
        Mobile.requestFocus();
    } else if (!validatePhone(Mobile.getText().toString())) {
        Mobile.setError("Invalid Mobile Number");
        Mobile.requestFocus();
    } else if (landline.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        landline.setError("Enter your landline Number");
        landline.requestFocus();
    } else if (Email.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        Email.setError("Enter your email");
        Email.requestFocus();
    } else if (Fbid.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        Fbid.setError("Enter your facebookId");
        Fbid.requestFocus();
    } else if (Occupation.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(RegisterFormActivity.this, "Fathers occupation", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    else if(Selection.getText().toString().equals(""))
     {
       Toast.makeText(RegisterFormActivity.this, "choose your gender", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (Business.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        Business.setError("please specify details");
        Business.requestFocus();
    } else if (Shortgoal.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        Shortgoal.setError("Your short term goal");
        Shortgoal.requestFocus();
    } else if (Longgoal.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        Longgoal.setError("Your long term goal");
        Longgoal.requestFocus();
    } else if (Size.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        Size.setError("Enter T-shirt Size");
        Size.requestFocus();
    } else if (Reference.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        Size.setError("Enter Reference name");
        Size.requestFocus();
    }
    else if(Form.getText().toString().equals("")){
        Form.setText("Enquiry Form");
    }

    else {
        String sname = Name.getText().toString().trim();
        String dob = Dob.getText().toString().trim();
        String cid = Collegeid.getText().toString().trim();
        String edu = Education.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String year = Year.getText().toString().trim();
        String addr = Address.getText().toString().trim();
        String pin = Pincode.getText().toString().trim();
        String mob = Mobile.getText().toString().trim();
        String lan = landline.getText().toString().trim();
        String email = Email.getText().toString().trim();
        String fbid = Fbid.getText().toString().trim();
        String focc = Occupation.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String bus= Selection.getText().toString().trim();
        String spe = Business.getText().toString().trim();
        String stgoal = Shortgoal.getText().toString().trim();
        String ltgoal = Longgoal.getText().toString().trim();
        String tsize = Size.getText().toString().trim();
         sub = Form.getText().toString().trim();
       // String ref = Reference.getText().toString().trim();
        //   String gender = Selection.getSelected().toString().toLowerCase();
        register(sname, dob, cid, edu, year, addr, pin, mob, lan, email, fbid, focc, bus, spe, stgoal, ltgoal, tsize, ref);
        msg = "<p><b>Name: </b>" + sname + "</p><p><b>Dob: </b>" + dob +
                "</p><p><b>Collegeid: </b>" + cid +"</p><p><b>Education: </b>" + edu +"</p><p><b>Year: </b>" + year +
                "</p><p><b>Address: </b>" + addr +"</p><p><b>Pincode: </b>" + pin +"</p><p><b>Mobile: </b>" + mob +"</p><p><b>landline: </b>" + lan +"</p><p><b>Email: </b>" + email +
                "</p><p><b>Fbid: </b>" + fbid +"</p><p><b>Occupation: </b>" + focc +"</p><p><b>Selection: </b>" + bus +"</p><p><b>Business: </b>" + spe +"</p><p><b>Shortgoal: </b>" + stgoal +
                "</p><p><b>Longgoal: </b>" + ltgoal +"</p><p><b>Size: </b>" + tsize +
                "</p><p><b>Reference: </b>" + Reference.getText().toString();
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "md-in-13.webhostbox.net");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("username", "password");

            }
        });
        if(DetectConnection
                .checkInternetConnection(RegisterFormActivity.this)){
            //Toast.makeText(RegisterFormActivity.this, "mailn", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            RetrieveFeedTask task = new RetrieveFeedTask();
            task.execute();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterFormActivity.this, "No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

    private void register(String sname, String dob, String cid, String edu, String year, String addr, String pin, String mob, String lan, String email, String fbid, String focc, String bus, String spe, String stgoal, String ltgoal, String tsize, String ref) {
        String urlSuffix = "?sname=" + sname + "&dob=" + dob + "&cid=" + cid + "&edu=" + edu + "&year=" + year + "&email=" + email + "&mob=" + mob + "&addr=" + addr + "&lan=" + lan + "&pin=" + pin + "&fbid=" + fbid + "&focc=" + focc + "&bus=" + bus + "&spe=" + spe + "&stgoal=" + stgoal + "&ltgoal=" + ltgoal + "&tsize=" + tsize + "&ref=" + ref;
        class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(RegisterFormActivity.this, "Please Wait", null, true, true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
              //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   try {

if (s.equals("1")) {
    Toast.makeText(RegisterFormActivity.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else if (s.equals("0")) {
    Toast.makeText(RegisterFormActivity.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
 }catch (Exception e){

   }
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String s = params[0];
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(REGISTER_URL + s);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                    String result;
                    result = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    return result;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        RegisterUser ru = new RegisterUser();
        ru.execute(urlSuffix);
    }
public class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("username"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.
                    parse("mailid"));
            // message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.
            //       parse("mailid"));
            message.setSubject(sub);
            //message.setContent(names, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
            message.setContent(msg, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8434843/1320616 While creating your table, mark the column as integer, auto increament. Then it will take the values for that column automatically without you inserting it manually

Comment: @ankit aggarwal my id is getting auto incremented. i need the autoincremented id from database and send it to a specified email

Comment: long generated_id = db.insert() this will return you the id

Answer (score 1):

Db `insert` function will return last inserted id after insertion and `-1` if there is any error.

Use this to get an id.

```
long id = db.insert(...);
```

Comment: i need to get the from db and make display it .

Comment: yes . this is whom ever register in the form they should get the id in mail.

Comment: long tick_no = id; i use this but it is getting 0 . but my db id is 10001

Comment: where is your database handler?

Comment: can u suggest me an code of example? i am inserting directly in to the db phpmyadmin

Comment: k let me try and say you

Comment: i need to display  success alert in db i have set 1 for success and o for error. my datas are been saved successfully but i ma getting any toast or alert after success can u please refer my code and say suggestion