# SQLiteDatabase: Android studio custom auto incrementation

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-studio

I am very new to Android studio, and SQLiteDatabases. I need help with the following:

The database, successfully creates and can display the values. However, I am trying to create a custom Unique ID for each patient when created. And the ID should be in-between 000000-999999 (6 Digit Unique ID).

The way the app works is:

```
1. User can "add patient"
2. User enters firstName and lastName
3. User than selects a department from a spinner
4. once the user has completed the above steps, he/she can click "Add Patient"
5. Then the values are displayed in a TabbedView, however the textView is horizontal rather than vertical.
6. and its displayed in a ListView
```

**I have been able to achieve all of the steps above. I just now need help with creating a unique id for the patients. Any help would greatly be appreciated**

Please look below for the code:

```
PatientDbHelper.java // Creates the tables and database

package tanav.sharma;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by Tanav on 11/4/2016.
 */
public class PatientDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "PATIENTINFO.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String CREATE_QUERY =
            "CREATE TABLE "+PatientInfo.NewPatientInfo.TABLE_NAME+" ("+ PatientInfo.NewPatientInfo.PATIENT_FNAME+ " TEXT,"+PatientInfo.NewPatientInfo.PATIENT_LNAME+" TEXT,"+PatientInfo.NewPatientInfo.PATIENT_DEPARTMENT+" TEXT);";

    public PatientDbHelper(Context context){

        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATIONS","Database created / opened ...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATIONS","Table created...");

    }

    public void addInformations(String fname, String lname, String department, SQLiteDatabase db){

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(PatientInfo.NewPatientInfo.PATIENT_FNAME,fname);
        contentValues.put(PatientInfo.NewPatientInfo.PATIENT_LNAME,lname);
        contentValues.put(PatientInfo.NewPatientInfo.PATIENT_DEPARTMENT,department);

        db.insert(PatientInfo.NewPatientInfo.TABLE_NAME, null,contentValues);

        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATIONS","One in row inserted...");
    }

    public Cursor getInformations(SQLiteDatabase db){
        Cursor cursor;
        String[] projections = {PatientInfo.NewPatientInfo.PATIENT_FNAME, PatientInfo.NewPatientInfo.PATIENT_LNAME, PatientInfo.NewPatientInfo.PATIENT_DEPARTMENT};
        cursor = db.query(PatientInfo.NewPatientInfo.TABLE_NAME,projections,null,null,null,null,null);
        return cursor;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

PatientInfo.java // this is names of the columns and etc..

```
package tanav.sharma;

/**
 * Created by Tanav on 11/4/2016.
 */
public class PatientInfo {

    public static abstract class NewPatientInfo{

        //public static final String PATIENT_ID = "patient_id";
        public static final String PATIENT_FNAME = "patient_fname";
        public static final String PATIENT_LNAME = "patient_lname";
        public static final String PATIENT_DEPARTMENT = "patient_department";

        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "patient_info";
    }
}
```

PatientInfoProvider.java

```
 package tanav.sharma;

    /**
     * Created by Tanav on 11/4/2016.
     */

public class PatientInfoProvider  {

        private String fname;
        private String lname;
        private String departments;

        public PatientInfoProvider(String fname, String lname, String departments){

            this.fname = fname;
            this.lname = lname;
            this.departments = departments;
        }

        public String getLname() {
            return lname;
        }

        public void setLname(String lname) {
            this.lname = lname;
        }

        public String getDepartments() {
            return departments;
        }

        public void setDepartments(String departments) {
            this.departments = departments;
        }

        public String getFname() {
            return fname;
        }

        public void setFname(String fname) {
            this.fname = fname;
        }
    }
```

The following file is to display the values in a listView with a customText view.

PatientAdapter.java

```
package tanav.sharma;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Tanav on 11/4/2016.
 */
public class PatientAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    List list = new ArrayList();


    public PatientAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    static class LayoutHandler{
        TextView FNAME,LNAME,Department;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Object object) {
        super.add(object);
        list.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        LayoutHandler layoutHandler;
        if(row == null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.display_all_patients,parent,false);

            layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
            layoutHandler.FNAME = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.patientNameFirst);
            layoutHandler.LNAME = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.patientNameLast);
            layoutHandler.Department = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.patientDepartment);

            row.setTag(layoutHandler);

        }else{
            layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler)row.getTag();

        }

        PatientInfoProvider patientInfoProvider = (PatientInfoProvider)this.getItem(position);
        layoutHandler.FNAME.setText(patientInfoProvider.getFname());
        layoutHandler.LNAME.setText(patientInfoProvider.getLname());
        layoutHandler.Department.setText(patientInfoProvider.getDepartments());

        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BaseColumns.html. Check _ID. You can use `BaseColumns._ID` and make it  `INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: Where would i put this? in my PatientDbHelper?

Comment: yes  `"CREATE TABLE "+PatientInfo.NewPatientInfo.TABLE_NAME+" (" + BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"......`

Comment: Okay that has worked. Is there a way I can personally message you? I have more questions

Comment: You can join chat rooms on stackoverflow. But there are rules to be followed. you need to ask a new question

Comment: You can also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434819/android-sqlite-auto-increment

Comment: @Raghunandan how can i join this chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of AUTOINCREMENT is to prevent the reuse of ID from previously deleted rows.

**PatientInfo.java**
The ID column has to be the first column of the table:

```
public static final String PATIENT_ID = "_id";
```

**PatientDbHelper.java**

```
private static final String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE " + PatientInfo.NewPatientInfo.TABLE_NAME + " ("
+ PatientInfo.NewPatientInfo.PATIENT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
+ PatientInfo.NewPatientInfo.PATIENT_FNAME+ " TEXT,"
+ PatientInfo.NewPatientInfo.PATIENT_LNAME+" TEXT,"
+ PatientInfo.NewPatientInfo.PATIENT_DEPARTMENT+" TEXT);";
```

in addInformations()

```
if ( id != 0 ) contentValues.put(PatientInfo.NewPatientInfo.PATIENT_ID,id);
```

---

**PatientInfoProvider.java**

```
private int id;
```

and

```
public void setId(int id) {
        this.id= id;
    }
```

or/and change the constructor

```
public PatientInfoProvider(int id, String fname, String lname, String departments){
this.id = id;
this.fname = fname;
this.lname = lname;
this.departments = departments; }
```

and you have to fill the ID field somewhere. If you need I could place the whole PatientInfoProvider.java

Okayy, So would my addInformation() look something like this?

```
public void addInformations(int id, String fname, String lname, String department, SQLiteDatabase db){

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        if ( id != 0 ) contentValues.put(PatientInfo.NewPatientInfo.PATIENT_ID, id);
        contentValues.put(PatientInfo.NewPatientInfo.PATIENT_FNAME,fname);
        contentValues.put(PatientInfo.NewPatientInfo.PATIENT_LNAME,lname);
        contentValues.put(PatientInfo.NewPatientInfo.PATIENT_DEPARTMENT,department);


        db.insert(PatientInfo.NewPatientInfo.TABLE_NAME, null,contentValues);

        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATIONS","One in row inserted...");
    }
```

Also it gives me the following error:

```
Error:(50, 28) error: method addInformations in class PatientDbHelper cannot be applied to given types;
required: int,String,String,String,SQLiteDatabase
found: String,String,String,SQLiteDatabase
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

So i tried to fix it by applying the following lines to my code.

```
public void addPatient(View view){

    int id; // Added this line
    String fname = PatientFirstName.getText().toString();
    String lname = PatientLastName.getText().toString();
    String dept = departments.getSelectedItem().toString();

    patientDbHelper = new PatientDbHelper(this);
    sqLiteDatabase = patientDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    patientDbHelper.addInformations(id,fname,lname,dept,sqLiteDatabase); //added 'id' in arguments..
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Data Saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    patientDbHelper.close();

}
```

However, the 'id' argument in addInformations comes underlined red and says Variable may have not been initialized.

I have fixed everything :)

Comment: Can you please ? i really need help, i havent sept in like 4 days

Comment: I need 2 other files to be sure. The method addInformations() is called  somewhere. There is the best place to create a new Unique ID. And you need to know the current max ID before you can create a new Unique ID. I need this file too to help you. Otherwise, you can send me the whole your project.

Comment: > However, the 'id' argument in addInformations comes underlined red and says Variable may have not been initialized

Comment: Yes, you need to initialize the variable "id".

Comment: Lool, i figured it out eventually. Thank alot for your help

Answer (score 0):

1- Generate a random number by Random() class in java .
2- Search in the database if this number is exist generate new number if not exist insert data with this number .

Note : Field **ID** is Primary but in not **Auto Increment**.