# How to delete database datas while using custom adapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite

I have customized listview in my AnaMenu activity and this listview has created by my database datas. I am trying to delete in my database all datas and I want to go MainActivity. When user"s click at the action bar logo.All datas will be deleted but When I try ,I get error message.My database has 4 columns.There is another important thing ; My AnaMenu activity has this. How can I fix it ?

This:(at my MainActivity.)

```
mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getData();
        sayı = data.getCount();

        if (sayı > 4){
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AnaMenu.class); startActivity(i);
            MainActivity.this.finish();
        }
```

How to create my custom adapter (at my AnaMenu activity) :

```
 while(data.moveToNext()){

            listDataId.add(data.getString(0));

            listData.add(data.getString(1));


            listDatanumber.add(data.getString(2));

            listDataoran.add(data.getString(3));


        }
        liste.setAdapter(oyunTextView);

    }


    class OyunTextView extends BaseAdapter {


        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return  listData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.oyuntextview, null);
            TextView namesbox = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.isim);
            sayılar = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sayı);
            namesbox.setText(listData.get(position));
            sayılar.setText(listDataoran.get(position));


            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

My database method :

```
public void deleteAllName(int id, String name ,String numara, String oran){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
                + COL1 + " = '" + id + "'"  + COL2 + " = '" + name  + COL3 + " = '"+ numara +
                " AND "  + COL4 + " = '" + oran  + "'";
        Log.d(TAG, "deleteName: query: " + query);
        Log.d(TAG, "deleteName: Deleting " + name + " from database.");
        db.execSQL(query);
    }
```

It is my code for logo icon:

```
  private void geri() {
      for (int d = 0 ; d<listDatanumber.size() ; d++) {
        int  id = Integer.parseInt(listDataId.get(d));
          String  isim = listData.get(d);
          String number = listDatanumber.get(d);
         String oran =   listDataoran.get(d);
         mDatabaseHelper.deleteAllName(id,isim,number,oran);
     }


        Intent ii = new Intent(AnaMenu.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(ii);
        AnaMenu.this.finish();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `AND` condition between your matching values and also `'" + name` has no matching `'`

```
String query = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
                + COL1 + " = '" + id   + "' AND "  
                // AND clause             ^^^^^
                + COL2 + " = '" + name + "' AND " 
                //  matching '            ^ 
                + COL3 + " = '"+ numara +"' AND "
                + COL4 + " = '" + oran  + "'";
```

Note : you can just delete a row using some unique column value or can make your `id` as  [`INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434819/android-sqlite-auto-increment)

Comment: Thanks for helping your answer is true.