# My App crashes upon creating Sqlite DB

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to use a database in my android app but when I start the activity that would use the DB helper/ Contract it crashes. I've tried some query validators and I don't seem to find any errors.
The following I use to use my dbhelper but the second line causes the crash.

```
    DBhelper dbHelper = new DBhelper(this);
    mDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Code for my dbcontract is:

```
public final class DBcontract {

    private DBcontract(){}

    public static class DB_table1 implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_Name = "Timer_table";
        public static final String COL_1 = "id";
        public static final String COL_2 = "Title";
        public static final String COL_3 = "Startvalue";
        public static final String COL_4 = "Endvalue";
        public static final String COL_5 = "Timer";

    }
}
```

and the dbhelper is:

```
public class DBhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "archeage.db";


    //Create table query
    public static final String CREATE_TABLE =
            ""      + "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_Name + " ( "
                    + DBcontract.DB_table1.COL_1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, "
                    + DBcontract.DB_table1.COL_2 + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                    + DBcontract.DB_table1.COL_3 + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                    + DBcontract.DB_table1.COL_4 + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                    + DBcontract.DB_table1.COL_5 + " INTEGER NOT NULL"
                    + ");";

    //delete table query
    public static final String DELETE_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_Name;

    public DBhelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(DELETE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

edit logcat errors:

```
04-09 13:27:51.233 28939-28939/com.example.xang.archeage E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error
04-09 13:27:51.236 28939-28939/com.example.xang.archeage E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.xang.archeage, PID: 28939
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.xang.archeage/com.example.xang.archeage.Timerpopup}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Timer_table ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, Title TEXT NOT NULL, Startvalue INTEGER NOT NULL, Endvalue INTEGER NOT NULL, Timer INTEGER NOT NULL);
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2779)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2844)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1572)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6361)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
                                                                            Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Timer_table ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, Title TEXT NOT NULL, Startvalue INTEGER NOT NULL, Endvalue INTEGER NOT NULL, Timer INTEGER NOT NULL);
                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:898)
                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:509)
                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1699)
                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1630)
                                                                               at com.example.xang.archeage.DBhelper.onCreate(DBhelper.java:41)
                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                                                                               at com.example.xang.archeage.Timerpopup.onCreate(Timerpopup.java:27)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6675)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2844) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1572) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6361) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

Comment: error log .....

Comment: remove .db from database name and try

Comment: please send code or error log so easy to  help you

Comment: removing .db didn't fix the issue also I just added the error log.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your issue is that **`AUTO_INCREMENT`** is not a keyword the correct keyword is **`AUTOINCREMENT`**.

However, you may wish to omit `AUTOINCREMENT` and just use `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` after reading :-

> The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and
>   disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is
>   usually not needed.

[SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

Answer (score 3):

No need to add AUTO_INCREMENT ; PRIMARY KEY will be incremented automatically. Remove AUTO_INCREMENT

or use AUTOINCREMENT
see this: [Android SQLite auto increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434819/android-sqlite-auto-increment/8434843)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is AUTO_INCREMENT, Make your query less complex.

```
String CREATE_EMPLOYEE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE Employee (Emp_Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Emp_Name TEXT, Emp_Phone TEXT, Emp_Email TEXT, Emp_Designation TEXT, Emp_Password TEXT)";
```